# Отправка запроса на сайт и получение ответа (Python Requests)

Tags: python, http, requests, response

Новичок в АйТи, поэтому прошу с пониманием и как можно проще.

Стоит задача отправки запроса на сайт (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/tools/primer-blast/) и получение ответа.

Проблема в том, что я не совсем понимаю как это происходит.
Использую Python Requests Post запрос с помощью которого могу вернуть HTML код, а что с ним делать дальше я не очень понимаю, внятных ответов я не нашел.
Если запускать сайт через браузер и делать все ручками, то сайт от начальной страницы перекидывает на другую, вот ОСНОВНОЙ ВОПРОС в том как мне узнать адрес этой новой страницы (не смотря в браузер конечно)?
Чтобы было понятно, начинаю я с этой страницы - https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/tools/primer-blast/
После ввода всех данных и нажатия кнопки submit (get primers), сайт перекидывает на примерно такой адрес:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/tools/primer-blast/primertool.cgi?ctg_time=1605352391&job_key=CRL3AuQIalJKJ04rLwV8VTQoTkQnN1NB
Вот как мне узнать эту часть (?ctg_time=1605352391&job_key=CRL3AuQIalJKJ04rLwV8VTQoTkQnN1NB) чтобы использовать ее в Requests для получения ответа?

Comment: А каких данных? А так, та кнопка находится на форме с id=searchForm и на форме есть ссылка на какой адрес отправлять запрос с данными формы (`action="./primertool.cgi"`), а те параметры из URL (ctg_time и job_key) скорее всего возвращается в ответе на запрос (в http заголовке Location будет адрес и http-статусом 302 (или другой из 300-тых), редирект) после чего браузер переходит по ссылке в http заголовке Location (кст, requests также перейдет по ссылке при редиректе и новый адрес будет в ответе на запрос по полю url, типа `rs = requests.post(...)` `print(rs.url)`)

Comment: Вот я Location в заголовке вообще не вижу, также как и редеректа.
Информация нужна такая:
(После заполнения формы и нажатия кнопки сабмит ручками и обработки запроса, идет перенаправление по этой ссылке -https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/tools/primer-blast/primertool.cgi?ctg_time=1605382421&job_key=kphN5Y5Kg-Kk2BPdHr0372SmJt1JtT3ASA)
И вот из этого мне нужны вот такие вот строки - <td>GAACCTTCCCCTGCAGTGTC</td> (последовательность букв может быть различной, вот я хочу их вылавливать).

Comment: Я могу как то направить полученную с помощью POST запроса форму по адресу ./primertool.cgi (action="./primertool.cgi") и получить ссылку по которой происходит редирект? Либо же уже сам ответ на выполненный автоматически редирект?
Я просто не понимаю как это можно сделать, отправить сразу форму по этому адресу и получить нужный ответ.

Comment: Отправляете запрос на адрес https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/tools/primer-blast/primertool.cgi, смотрите как это выглядит в инспекторе браузера (F12) на вкладке сети (заголовки, данные). Еще, я заметил, что у той формы задан `enctype=multipart/form-data`, чтобы в таком же виде отправить данные нужно их составить как словарь и передать в атрибут `files`, типа такого: `rs = requests.post(url, files={"INPUT_SEQUENCE": "GAACCTTCCCCTGCAGTGTC"})`, а чтобы увидеть что отправляет requests: https://clck.ru/RvfJ5

Comment: Если вам тяжело разобраться, как и что делает `requests`, то советую попробовать сделать то же самое с `selenium`. Это средство управления обычным браузером. Фактически, вы через код делаете то же самое, что и руками, но при этом в комплекте есть средства работы с элементами страницы - вы можете программно нажимать кнопки, вводить информацию, а браузер заодно обработает весь необходимый JS-код (чего не сделает `requests`). В дальнейшем, можно переключить браузер в "безголовый" режим, когда окно не отображается на рабочем столе, но все действия выполняются точно так же